# Separating Axis Theorem Implementation always returning true. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics, separating-axis-theorem

I'm trying to implement collision detection for concave polygons in Javascript/p5.js using the Separating Axis Theorem. I've been following the following tutorial on how to use it: http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/

However, my check is always returning true, no matter the positioning of the two polygons. Here's my code:

```
function SAT(shape1, shape2)
{
    let axes1 = getAxes(shape1);
    let axes2 = getAxes(shape2);
    let colliding = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < axes1.length; i++)
    {
        let axis = axes1[i];
        let p1 = shape1.project(axis);
        let p2 = shape2.project(axis);
        if (!p1.overlap(p2)) colliding = false;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < axes2.length; i++)
    {
        let axis = axes2[i];
        let p1 = shape1.project(axis);
        let p2 = shape2.project(axis);
        if (!p1.overlap(p2)) colliding = false;
    }
    return colliding;
}

function getAxes(shape)
{
    let axes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < shape.vertices.length; i++)
    {
        let p1 = shape.vertices[i];
        let p2 = shape.vertices[i + 1 == shape.vertices.length ? 0 : i + 1];
        let edge = p1.sub(p2);
        let normal = createVector(-edge.y, edge.x);
        axes[i] = normal;
    }
    return axes;
}

class Projection
{

    constructor(min, max)
    {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    overlap(other)
    {
        if (this.max < other.min || other.max < this.min) return false;
        else return true;
    }

}

class PolygonCollider extends Component
{

    constructor(gameObject)
    {
        super(gameObject);
        this.untransformedVertices = [];
        this.vertices = [];
        ...
    }

    setVerts(verts)
    {
        if (verts && verts.length > 2)
        {
            this.untransformedVertices = verts;
            this.vertices = this.transform.getTransformedPoints(verts);
            return this;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    project(axis)
    {
        let min = axis.dot(this.vertices[0]);
        let max = min;
        for (let i = 1; i < this.vertices.length; i++)
        {
            let p = axis.dot(this.vertices[i]);
            if (p < min) min = p;
            else if (p > max) max = p;
        }
        return new Projection(min, max);
    }

    update()
    {
        this.vertices = this.transform.getTransformedPoints(this.untransformedVertices);
    }

    ...

}
```

Vertices are transformed with the following function, using a defined scale, rotation and position:

```
getTransformedPoints(points)
{
    let transformed = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        let rX = ((this.scale.x * points[i].x) * Math.cos(this.rotation)) - ((this.scale.y * points[i].y) * Math.sin(this.rotation));
        let rY = ((this.scale.x * points[i].x) * Math.sin(this.rotation)) + ((this.scale.y * points[i].y) * Math.cos(this.rotation));
        transformed[i] = createVector(rX + this.position.x, rY + this.position.y);
    }
    return transformed;
}
```

The SAT method is always returning true. I believe I'm checking for the overlap incorrectly, but I can't figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out the issue with my implementation lied with p5.js, a library I am using in this case.

In the `getAxes` method, I was subtracting `p1` from `p2` using p5's built in `p5.Vector.sub` function. This didn't have the desired effect. I'm not sure, but I believe the issue was that it wasn't creating a new vector that was the difference of the equation. I fixed this simply by creating the new vector myself as such: `createVector(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y);`